# Outlook 2013 - Send To-Mail Recipient not working

Tags: gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013

I use web-based gmail, but I would like to setup Outlook so I can right-click on a file and use Send To-Mail Recipient. So, I created an account, but did not configure the gmail IMAP: I just put 127.0.0.1 as the IMAP server.

I correctly configured the SMTP part. It works: In outlook, I can create a message and send it.

However, the Send To does not work. I get this error:

[image]

There are no other accounts configured in Outlook. I'm on Win8.1 x64.

Is it due to my account not being completely configured? Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control panel-->default programs for me:
[image]

([Bigger image](http://i61.tinypic.com/2wei1x0.png))

And then click here:
[image]

([Bigger image](http://i57.tinypic.com/2wdcbyg.png))

And there click for outlook, and now you mark as default. :)

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Working now. The MAPI Send Mail option was not associated with Outlook.

Comment: Which version outlook you have?
I mean your're up to date all upgrades?